# foreach with serial and parallel backend giving different results

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

I have a strange case where using `foreach` with a serial and parallel backend gives different results the first time I call but then later on both results matches. I used `RNG` to make the results reproducible for the same `seed`

Below is a sample function to explain the scenario :

```
func <- function(ncores = NULL, seed = 1234){
  if (!is.null(ncores)){ # this block registers for parallel backend
    cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    registerDoRNG(seed, once = TRUE)
    on.exit(stopCluster(cl)) 
  } else {              # this block registers for serial computation
    registerDoSEQ() 
    registerDoRNG(seed, once = TRUE)
  }
  w = foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = 'c') %dorng% {
    mean(sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))
  }
  attr(w, "rng") <- NULL
  return(w)
}

# first time running below 2 lines
# case 1 : serial
w1 <- func(ncores = NULL)
# Case 2 : parallel
w2 <- func(ncores= 5)
identical(w1, w2)

# second time running below 2 lines
# case 1: serial
w3 <- func(ncores = NULL)
# case 2: parallel 
w4 <- func(ncores= 5)

identical(w1, w2)
# [1] FALSE
identical(w3, w4)
# [1] TRUE
```

Am i missing something while registering sequential process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the following expression:

```
w = foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = 'c', .options.RNG=seed) %dorng% {
    mean(sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))}
```

You can find an explanation at the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf).

So your function looks like this:

```
func <- function(ncores = NULL, seed = 1234){
  if (!is.null(ncores)){ # this block registers for parallel backend
    cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    on.exit(stopCluster(cl)) 
  } else {              # this block registers for serial computation
    registerDoSEQ() 
  }
  w = foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = 'c', .options.RNG=seed) %dorng% {
    mean(sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE))
  }
  attr(w, "rng") <- NULL
  return(w)
}
```

Comment: i had gone through the vignette before.. but didn't find the reason for this behaviour. Bdw your solution solved the problem +1. Do you know why `registerDoRNG()` was having that issue?